# Which operations will invalidate constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout

`UIView`'s `updateConstraints` method has a note:

> You must not invalidate any constraints as part of your constraint
>   update phase. You also must not invoke a layout or drawing phase as
>   part of constraint updating.

It is not clear to me what would invalidate constraints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through some experiments, I found that simply adding, removing or editing constraints will not automatically have `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` get called. In fact, I can't find any way to get `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` called automatically by the system. Together with my observation that `updateConstraints` will not be called without `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` being called first, I think the only meaningful way to *invalidate any constraints* is by calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` myself. Thus the implication of the note in the question post is:

> You must not call **[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]** or **[self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize]** in **updateConstraints**.

Comment: that's the purpose of setNeedsUpdateConstraints. It's not a system invoked method. It's a method provided to the programmer to notify the Auto Layout runtime that constraints need to be updated. The runtime will then do this at the appropriate time. It's provided because you should not call updateConstraints directly.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question!

Richard Warren covers this in his blog tutorial [UNDERSTANDING AUTO LAYOUT](http://www.freelancemadscience.com/fmslabs_blog/2012/12/29/understanding-auto-layout.html):

> If we want to invalidate a view’s constraints, we should remove the
>   old constraints, then call setNeedsUpdateConstraints. Our custom
>   updateConstraints or updateViewConstraints methods can then provide
>   the new constraints.

Constraints should not be invalided in the `updateConstraints` method. This is explicitly stated in the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW158):

> Custom views that set up constraints themselves should do so by
>   overriding this method. When your custom view notes that a change has
>   been made to the view that invalidates one of its constraints, it
>   should immediately remove that constraint, and then call
>   setNeedsUpdateConstraints to note that constraints need to be updated.
>   Before layout is performed, your implementation of updateConstraints
>   will be invoked, allowing you to verify that all necessary constraints
>   for your content are in place at a time when your custom view’s
>   properties are not changing.
>
> **You may not invalidate any constraints as part of your constraint
>   update phase**. You also may not invoke a layout or drawing phase as
>   part of constraint updating.

This is different to the view controller equivalent `updateViewConstraints`. There is no similar stipulation not to invalidate constraints in that method.  Certainly, [Erica Sadun's](http://ericasadun.com) [book](http://ericasadun.com/2013/03/12/ios-auto-layout-demystified-arriving-in-april/)  shows sample code that does just that.

Comment: `updateConstraints` is for updating constraints, right? Isn't constraints removal one kind of constraints update? Am I allowed to remove constraints in `updateConstraints`?

Comment: added to answer with Apple's guidelines as stated in UIView docs above